# Why is my Apache Virtual Hosts configuration not working correctly?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

## Background

I have been using an Apache server with only one site and this has been working really well. My working single-site config is at the bottom of the question.  Recently, I have had to create two more sites locally, and I found [this](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/apache-on-macos/) guide that showed how to do this. I also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339044/how-to-run-multiple-sites-on-one-apache-instance) stack overflow question which also helped me a lot.

My problem is that when I visit the three hosts I made in `/etc/hosts` and configured in `httpd-vhosts.conf`, it is not working and says `its-site.test refused to connect.` when I try to visit it in browser.

## Attempted Solutions

I attempted to resolve the issue by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504003/apache-virtual-hosts-not-working-as-expected) stack overflow question which helped me to understand the configuration much better, but it is still not working and results in the same issue.

After spending a few days trying solutions and going through the Apache docs, I opened a [new Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76672484/why-is-my-apache-virtual-hosts-configuration-not-working-correctly) and was subsequently directed to this site for further help.

Needless to say I am very new to Apache so I might be overlooking something obvious.

## My intended setup

I have three different sites which I want to use named virtual hosts to access in browser during my development process. Rather than using one local host and a few named-based virtual hosts, I wanted all three to be name-based virtual hosts with the below URLs:

- its-site.test
- its-cab.test
- its-gallery.test

If this isn't recommended for some reason, I am flexible on the names, but I wanted to use name-based virtual hosts and three different URLs as the sites are unrelated.

## Hosts file

`/etc/hosts`

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       its-site.test
127.0.0.1       its-cab.test
127.0.0.1       its-gallery.test
```

## httpd configuration

`/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

```
Listen 80

Include /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
ServerName localhost:80

# Also enabled PHP but not including the config here as it may not be relevant
```

## vhosts configuration

`/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName its-site.test
    ServerAlias *.its-site.test
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-site/web"

    <directory "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-site/web">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName its-cab.test
    ServerAlias *.its-cab.test
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-cab/web"

    <directory "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-cab/web">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName its-gallery.test
    ServerAlias *.its-gallery.test
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-gallery/web"

    <directory "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-gallery/web">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## Question

Does anybody see where I made a mistake with this configuration and can point me towards the solution?

## Additional Information

- M1 Macbook Air
- Apache and PHP installed using homebrew

## Previous Single Site working Config

As stated earlier, I had this working well when I was serving only one site. My only configuration was with `httpd.conf` and did not configure `/etc/hosts` or `httpd-vhosts.conf`. My working `httpd.conf` file looked like:

```
Listen 80
DocumentRoot "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-gallery/web"
<Directory "/Users/ciesinsg/Documents/Repositories/its-gallery/web">

# Also enabled PHP
```

I removed the `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` when I configured VirtualHosts.

Comment: is this a Mac Laptop?

Comment: An error "refused to connect" suggest that nothing is listening (on port 80) . IIRC  by default apache httpd packaged by brew only opens port 8080 and not the default http port 80. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Comment: Yes this is a mac laptop. And I also configured `Listen 80` in `httpd.conf` which worked in my single-site config when I visited https://localhost:80 as the post I was following informed me of the same issue with port 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem using the below solution:

## Test PHP

First, I tested my configurations in `etc/hosts` using ping:

```
ciesinsg@NB-00304-H14872 ~ % ping its-site.test
PING its-site.test (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
```

This confirmed that the site was routing to the right IP matching my config.

## Check Virtual Hosts

This was done manually by referring to [these](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) docs and double checking the [guide](https://www.git-tower.com/blog/apache-on-macos/) I followed. I am not aware of any tests to confirm the configuration is working correctly, but after reading a few guides and docs about virtual hosts, I was pretty confident that the configuration did not have any issues and the problem must be elsewhere.

## Check httpd.conf

This configurations is the longest out of the ones I listed by default. Consequently, this was a manual process. My solution involved opening `httpd-default.conf` which is an adjacent configuration file that appears to have the default configurations from the `httpd.conf` file. On the Homebrew installation of Apache, this is located in the `/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/` where the `httpd.conf` file is also located. I compared these two configurations side by side and removed my configurations from my earlier attempts.

In my case, I found that I had accidentally duplicated my PHP configuration in the `httpd.conf` file and in `httpd-php.conf` file. I removed all of my configurations and followed through the guide once again, ensuring that my `Include` and `LoadModule` statements were placed after the same statements.

After removing my configurations and configuring it more carefully, I tested the sites in the browser and they were all working as expected.